# Unable to build jar project

Tags: java, jar

I need help with building jar file. I always getting message Error: Could not find or load main class Main when trying to execute jar file.

[image: This is my project Structure]

My MANIFEST.MF here:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main
```

And my Main.java file:

```
public class Main {    
public static final Charset ISO_8859_1 = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1;
public static final Charset UTF_8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
for (String arg : args) {
        System.out.println("Arg " + arg);
    }
//Other code removed
}
```

I really don't know what I am doing wrong when building jar file that it doesn't see Main class.

Comment: How do you run the jar?

Comment: Via .bat file with the following content:
@echo off
for %%i in (*.xls*) do  call java -jar SimplyVAT.jar %CD%\%%i %CD%\output\%%i

Comment: Also try to run via PowerShell with command: java -jar SimplyVAT.jar

Comment: Judging from the screenshot, it seems that your class is called `SimplyVAT.main` and not `Main`. How are you building the JAR file (Maven, Gradle, Ant, IntelliJ)?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ

Comment: Just tryed to change Manifest to:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: SimplyVAT.main

and now getting error: Error: Could not find or load main class SimplyVAT.main

Comment: There is an environment variable called `CLASSPATH` which includes directories where Java looks for all class files and if it doesn't find your main class there then it throws "**Error: Could not find or load main class ABC**"

You need to set it to desired location.

Answer (score 0):

After I added env variable it start to see main, but now I am getting another crash:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    org/apache/poi/openxml4j/exceptions/InvalidFormatException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

It looks that java don't see library files in my jar file. If I check jar file with 7zip I can see library files inside of it.
[image]